# Can't understand a 'but' word usage [Daniel Defoe]

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can someone please explain me why Daniel Defoe uses a 'but' word literally everywhere? (See photos, last string in both occasions). Thanks a lot for your answers!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking up _but_ in a dictionary? You’re looking at the adverbial sense here.

Comment: @Janus There are different usages here. The first two and the fourth instances are the limiting modifier (traditionally, focusing adverb) usage. _Give me but a good ship ... = Give me nothing more than a good ship ... = Just /Merely / Only give me a good ship ...._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The question specifies that it’s only two specific instances that are being asked about.

Comment: "Give us but a good ship"  = give us merely a good ship = all we would need is a good ship (see Lawrence's answer below and Edwin's comment above).

Comment: The same usage occurs in several places (but a young sailor, but little way). = just a novice sailor ...  only a little progress.

Comment: @Taras Please consider the accessibility of your question and actually type out the part which is in doubt. Screen-reading software doesn't generally do OCR on photographs.

Comment: @Janus Oops. Happily, they're also the limiting modifier jobbies. Unless '_But_ it was ...' is included: the contrastive sentence-connector, virtually equivalent to however + comma.

Answer (score 3):

The etymological meaning of ‘but’ is ‘outside’; whence ‘except’. The instances you cite are elliptic for ‘not but’, or ‘naught but’, that is, ‘only’.

O.E.D.:

> 6. a. By the omission of the negative accompanying the preceding verb (see C. 4a), but passes into the adverbial sense of: Nought but,
>      no more than, only, merely. (Thus the earlier ‘he nis but a child’ is
>      now ‘he is but a child’; here north. dialects use nobbut prep., conj.,
>      and adv.   = nought but, not but, ‘he is nobbut a child’.)
>
> 1393   Langland Piers Plowman C. xvii. 359   He comeþ but selde. a1400
>   (▸a1325)    Cursor Mundi (Vesp.) l. 4322   Bettur..þan folu þi prai
>   þat es bot tint. c1400   Mandeville's Trav. 157   The folk..han but
>   litille appetyt to mete. c1440   Anc. Cookery in Coll. Ordinances
>   Royal Househ. (1790) 465   Take rys, and gif hom but a boyle. 1512
>   Act 3 Hen. VIII vi. Preamble,   The forsaid penaltie expressed in the
>   said Statute is but xxs. 1617   S. Collins Epphata to F. T. vi. 239
>   It was impious..but euen to touch the bodies of Saints dead. 1647   A.
>   Cowley Spring in Mistress ii,   Could they remember but last year.
>   1732   G. Berkeley Alciphron I. i. iii. 13   Do but consider this.
>   1766   O. Goldsmith Vicar of Wakefield I. iii. 17   Premature
>   consolation is but the remembrancer of sorrow. 1794   R. Burns (title)
>   My love she's but a lassie yet. 1876   J. R. Green Short Hist. Eng.
>   People (1882) i. §3. 30   In arms the kingdom had but a single rival.