# How should I understand this sentence in the movie Bridgerton?

Tags: grammar

I just watched Bridgerton Season 1 Ep. 2 at scene 14.47 and the old lady goes

- "You ate but not one bite at tea, my dear!"

The context is that 3 people were having tea together and the old lady complained about the young lady being not well fed.

What stucture is that?

Normally we have [verb] + [not] + [NP1] + [but] + [NP2] , meaning [verb NP2 only].

*He scored not one goal, but 3* = *He scored 3 goals*.

But with this sentence, I'm completely in the dark.

Comment: It means she didn't eat anything.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments. Write an answer and explain it.

Comment: Yes please explain it to me. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'd say it's non-standard nowadays. It doesn't seem to be the 'nobbut' usage [[I can't understand a _but_ word usage by Daniel Defoe.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/270945/cant-understand-a-but-word-usage-daniel-defoe/270953#270953)]

Answer (score 2):

It's not standard. It seems to me a muddle of the following:

- not one bite (i.e. no bites at all)
- but one bite (i.e. only one bite)

The latter usage is sense 1 of [the adverb "but"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/but#Adverb).

The old lady's sentence, with "but not one bite", is not grammatical, but then the scriptwriter might well have deliberately made the character say that, to show a peculiarity of  that character's speech.

Comment: Can you support your statement `"but not one bite", is not grammatical`? While the construction may not be orthodox, what rule of grammar is it breaking? In particular, how is this use of 'but' not an example of **sense 3** of the definition you've linked to, i.e. as an *intensifier*?